# Python: how to print string and numbers from a list in 1 line?

Tags: python, list

```
array = [1,2,3]
print("List: ")
for i in array:
    print(i, end=" ")
-------
```

I want the output to look like `List: 1 2 3`

How can I achieve this in Python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give the value for `end` parameter in the first print statement

```
array = [1,2,3]
print("List: ",end="")
for i,x in enumerate(array):
    print(array[i], end=" ") if len(array) != x else print(array[i])
print("foo")
```

#### Output

> List: 1 2 3
>   foo

Comment: One bug. After the printing the last num, if another print is used then it will be like `List: 1 2 3foo`.

Answer (score 0):

```
print(f"List: {array[0]} {array[1]} {array[2]}")
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe :

```
>>> a = [1,2,3]
>>> b = [str(i) for i in a]
>>> print "List :"+", ".join(b)
List :1, 2, 3
```